# Domain of integral with respect to probability law.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable. Let $P_X$ be its probability law. Does it make sense to write
$\int_2^\infty P_X(dx)$?
I think that $\int_{[2,\infty)}P_X(dx)$ may not be equal to $\int_{(2,\infty)}P_X(dx)$, because it might happen that $P(X=2)>0$. Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If $\mu$ is a general Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ measure we cannot write $\int_a^{b} f \, d\mu$; we have to specify whether the interval is open, closed are half open (and which of the end points is included if it is half open). If $ \mu \{x\}=0$ for all $x$ then we can write  $\int_a^{b} f \, d\mu$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: That comment seems like a complete answer to me?